# How do I override bootstrap.js?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using a Bootstrap 3 child theme in Drupal 7. All is working well, except I can't seem to be able to override bootstrap.js at sites/all/themes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js in my own theme.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably using a CDN, as per https://drupal.org/node/1978010.

> Bootstrap Methods
>   There are currently two types of supported methods for adding Bootstrap into your sub-theme. By default, the Bootstrap base theme enables a CDN to provide the necessary files.
>   If this method suits you then you can skip this step.

Comment: No. He is referencing another thing, not CDN related. He is talking about the file that connects Bootstrap to Drupal behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Inside template.php of your theme:

```
/**
* Implements hook_js_alter().
*/
function client_js_alter(&$js) {
    // Path to your theme
    $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'client');
    // Your overwrites
    $bootstrap_fix = $theme_path . '/js/bootstrap_fix.js';
    $js[$bootstrap_fix] = drupal_js_defaults($bootstrap_fix);
    $js[$bootstrap_fix]['group'] = JS_THEME;
    $js[$bootstrap_fix]['scope'] = 'footer';
    $js[$bootstrap_fix]['weight'] = 2;
}
```